# Practical way of sending a message to a group of connected clients

Tags: socket.io

I'm using rooms at the moment however I think the way I'm going about using them isn't practical. This is a portion of my code.

```
// Add clients that are to be notified to the users room.
for(var c in clients)
{
    if(_.indexOf(data.notify, clients[c].id) != -1)
    {
        clients[c].socket.join(data.user_id);
    }
}

// Emit to all that are now in the room.
io.sockets.in(data.user_id).emit('notification', data);

// Remove everyone from this users room so it's free for the next notification.
for(var c in clients)
{
    if(clients[c].id in data.notify)
    {
        clients[c].socket.leave(data.user_id);
    }
}
```

So as you can see I add the correct clients to a room which is an ID of a user who has updated something. Then once I emit the notification to the group I remove all the clients once more from the room to keep it free.

Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: so user x has a room, room - x.  why do you want to remove all the clients that are in that room after the notification?  You could just remove clients that leave the room when they leave, but otherwise keep them in that room, and then anytime you do a notification, it will just be to users in that room.  I will give a more thorough answer with code sample below, if that is the case.